# ¿Cómo pasar un parámetro a una "corrección" en AutoHotKey?

Tags: variables, script, autohotkey

tengo un script como el siguiente para programar en Arduino:

```
::dl::
send,delay();
return

::dw::
send,digitalWrite(,);
return

::dr::
send,digitalRead();
return
```

Esto hace que sea mas rápido escribir el código, pero me gustaría pasarles los parámetros en conjunto con cada palabra clave o Hotkey, por ejemplo: al escribir " dr**5**  " de como resultado

```
digitalRead(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Estuve aprendiendo un poco más sobre las variables en autohotkey, pero creo que está aún no es la mejor forma para este caso, **pero funciona:**

```
::dr::
Input, t, L1 V
send,{BackSpace}digitalRead(%t%);
return
```

En este caso tras escribir la palabra clave (en este caso "dr") y dar un espacio se espera un carácter que se añadirá como parámetro.

El inconveniente en este caso es que se debe especificar la cantidad de caracteres del parámetro(lo que varía en cada caso), por lo que otra solución seria llevar el índice directamente a la posición del parámetro de la siguiente manera:

```
::dr::
send,digitalRead();
Send,{Left}{Left}
return
```